# Network request failed React native fetch (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, https, fetch

I have a case when fetching SSL API I get the request fetched successfully on IOS

But on android I have an exception as following

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (index.android.bundle:12910)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (index.android.bundle:13813)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (index.android.bundle:15406)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (index.android.bundle:15262)
at index.android.bundle:15357
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (index.android.bundle:3851)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (index.android.bundle:2090)
at index.android.bundle:1948
at MessageQueue.__guard (index.android.bundle:2062)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue 
(index.android.bundle:1947)
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Only SSL fetch on android fail. If i fetched HTTP API it works

Edit #1

React-native version:0.44.3

Android emulator version: 7.0

Tested devices: Samsung galaxy j7 prime(Real device) and pixel 2 XL (emulator)

Edit #2

this the code

```
try {
    let url = "https://URL_HERE";
    console.log(url);
    let bodyData = {
        user: {
            email: user.email//...etc
        }
    };
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
    });
    res.code = response.status;
    if (res.code === 200) {
        let responseJson = await response.json();
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

TIA

Comment: Allloush, Can you add some code snippets from the project (including fetch statement), so that I can try replicate on my machine ?

Comment: @Susth sure I will edit